# Xen domU start up hangs, cannot connect to vbd

Tags: virtual-machine, arch-linux, xen

I am trying to build a Xen domU on my Arch x64 Linux. I have started dom0 successfully. My Xen kernel version is **Linux arch xen 3.2.9-1-ARCH**, my domU config file is

```
name = "arch0"
memory = 256
kernel = "/boot/vmlinuz-linux"
ramdisk = "/boot/initramfs-linux-xen.img"
disk = [ 'phy:/dev/sdb1,xvda,w' ]
root = "/dev/xvda ro"
dhcp="dhcp"
#vif = [ 'mac=08:00:27:eb:41:01' ]
hostname = "arch_domU0"
```

After I ran *xm creaet domU -c*, the terminal hangs at **Using config file "./domU0".**. And in the /var/log/xen/xend.log file, the last line says:

```
[2012-03-09 22:46:58 2802] DEBUG (DevController:628) hotplugStatusCallback /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/11/51712/hotplug-status.
```

I read the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xen) thoroughly, but cannot find an help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a Arch only issue. This **[post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1070592)** has the solution.